# How I can extract just some fields from a CSV line of text

Tags: text-processing, awk, command-line, csv

I need help to find out a way to extract specific information of the lines below using Linux commands.

```
391,(INSIDE-A),to,(OUTSIDE-A),source,static,SRV_I_N1909,SRV_NAT_I_N1909,destination,static,REDE_AMX_MCK,REDE_AMX_MCK,translate_hits=4399,untranslate_hits=4413
431,(INSIDE-A),to,(OUTSIDE-A),source,static,WK_I_5.5.4.56,SRV_NAT_10.9.3.212,translate_hits=284903,untranslate_hits=8472
432,(INSIDE-A),to,(OUTSIDE-A),source,dynamic,GRP_WKS_HOSTS_,WK_NAT_10.9.7.229,destination,static,G_SRV_ENG_CL,G_SRV_E_CL,translate_hits=0,untranslate_hits=0
436,(INSIDE-A),to,(OUTSIDE-A),source,static,SRV_I_ND007,NAT_10.9.4.238,destination,static,R_MCK,R_MCK,translate_hits=1966,untranslate_hits=1966
437,(INSIDE-A),to,(OUTSIDE-A),source,static,WK_I_5.8.104.120,NAT_A_10.9.7.245,translate_hits=84908,untranslate_hits=1965
440,(INSIDE-A),to,(OUTSIDE-A),source,dynamic,REDE_NET1,NAT_A_10.9.7.247,destination,static,SRV_BT_10.3.33.9,SRV_BT_10.3.33.9,translate_hits=18970,untranslate_hits=18970
```

As you can see, the lines are different, desired information:

```
440, translate_hits=18970,untranslate_hits=18970
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming no field in the file has an embedded comma or newline character (i.e. it's a "simple CSV file"), you can get the first and the last two fields from each line with

```
$ awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { print $1, $(NF-1), $NF }' file.csv
391,translate_hits=4399,untranslate_hits=4413
431,translate_hits=284903,untranslate_hits=8472
432,translate_hits=0,untranslate_hits=0
436,translate_hits=1966,untranslate_hits=1966
437,translate_hits=84908,untranslate_hits=1965
440,translate_hits=18970,untranslate_hits=18970
```

`NF` is a special variable that contains the number of fields on each line, and we set both input and output field separator to a comma.  In the `print` block, we print only the fields that we're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
grep -o "^[0-9]*\|,tran.*$" file | sed 'N;s/\n,/,/'
```

Output:

```
391,translate_hits=4399,untranslate_hits=4413
431,translate_hits=284903,untranslate_hits=8472
432,translate_hits=0,untranslate_hits=0
436,translate_hits=1966,untranslate_hits=1966
437,translate_hits=84908,untranslate_hits=1965
440,translate_hits=18970,untranslate_hits=18970
```

Comment: For the inserted space on awk, just edit to `" " $13` to concatenate a space before the field.

Comment: To process a whole file in this format, drop the echo pipeline and add the input file name to the end of the awk command. No need to read the file via shell line by line.

Comment: Notice how the number of fields on each line varies slightly...

Comment: @Paul_Pedant "o process a whole file in this format, drop the echo pipeline" That was my first thought, but OP in it's original (not edited as it is now), didn't mention a file, he referred only as ["this line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/578862/1). But nonetheless, I could've just assume it was a file. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda in it's [original (not edited as it is now)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/578862/1), OP didn't mention a file, he referred only as "this line", that's all that was. But nonetheless, I could've just assume it was a file, or ask the OP for more information. I'll edit the answer. I'll make a revision of the answer now that' is edited also.